# How to compare differently formatted addresses (php / mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, comparison

I am working on an established php mysql web application with some fairly big data.

As part of the data management routines new data on addresses are added to the database (import) from two different sources.

All of the addresses in this data are from the UK.

The application has used `addressRecord.address1 = address1 AND addressRecord.postcode = postcode` as a collision detection before inserting a new address, or associating a record with an existing address.

The trouble is the collision test is not conclusive.  As the two different sources of data have provided somewhat different address formats.

**source 1**

```
    address1 = 'FLAT N, RICHMOND HILL GATE, 1'

    address2 = 'RICHMOND HILL DRIVE'

    address3 = 'BOURNEMOUTH'

    postcode = 'BH2 6LT'
```

**source 2**

```
    address1 = 'Flat N'

    address2 = 'Richmond Hill Gate'

    address3 = '1 Richmond Hill Drive'

    postcode = 'BH2 6LT'
```

Because this is an established application this duplication already exists in the address table, which I must deal with, but also new data is continually imported and must be related to an address record.

So I am looking for a conclusive (almost conclusive might do) way to compare addresses with slightly different formatting, that is also performant (10's millions of rows of data).

I have so far considered calculating an identification field, which can be augmented to the existing data, and calculated for the new imports, that may for example be the 3 address fields concatenated, with all punctuation removed, or perhaps just the numbers.  or  ...   Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: FWIW, this is a very common issue. There are companies that offer mailing list de-duping as a service, it is a significant undertaking. How to tell that "123 Richmond Way" is the same address as "123 Richmond" and "123 SE Richmond Wy.", and that "123 SE Richmond Wy. Ste 123" is the same and the preferred, being more complete? You're going to have to dip into a lot of buckets to solve this. I've used Google maps to geolocate the addresses, the US postal service offers a change-of-address verification, and there are other half-measures, but any big database full of people struggles with this.

Comment: Another note: I've also used a strategy where I parse the addresses and format them consistently in one pass (normalize the data), THEN do a matching string comparison as a second pass. I used this function to parse the addresses -- it works for US addresses with some success: https://gist.github.com/GRMule/7775384 -- so I looped every record, normalized the address, wrote the record, etc. I have not tried it on UK mailing addresses, but you can see what is involved there!

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the useful comments and especially the code sample which has given me some ideas.  The normalisation idea is exactly what I am looking for.  Better formatted UK address data that I have seen splits bulilding name or number, secondary element such as flat , and street name into 3 exact fields .  I wonder if this was automated but I suspect manual input or verification.  Thanks.

Comment: Struggling with this type of data is what leads some system designers to using extremely specific address fields, instead of just "Address", you have "House Number", "Street name", a dropdown with the street types (Blvd, Ave, Rd, etc), a separate field for box numbers, a separate one for suite... you get the picture. That is **extremely annoying** for your users, though, so unless you're doing something highly specific to addresses (like real estate), I would keep on the track you're going down and make it your problem to clean the data, rather than the users'

Comment: I suggest to check prices for l products offered by companies that also deliver updates on a regular basis. In Germany, we use uniserve for that, they might have versions for other countries too. You can normalize and verify addresses. (No I'm not connected to them, but used their software in the past and found it really useful. Might be expensive, though)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert all addresses to a normalized address format like @chris said. I don't think you will be able to do that 'on-the-fly' in your database. You will be depending on code to do that and store the results in the database. The biggest problem you have there is that the data you have is missing integrity: The same address with or without zip code; Addresses with the same zip code but with a different street name or city; the same address with a different zip code; Street names that are written differently, 'W Churchill Ln' vs 'Winston Churchill Lane'. You will need fuzzy logic to let a computer decide what is right. 
Data from various sources might be consistent in formatting per source, you might gain from this in some way. The other thing is that one source will be more reliable than the others, you will also be able to use this to your advantage.